# Upload a file in Onedrive exception

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive

I would upload a file to onedrive, I created a method for signing , i insert wl.skydrive_update scope,the problem is in the upload method generates me an exception, I call the method with a button this is the code:

```
 private async void upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(defaultDb != null)
        {
            try
            {
                    // Upload to OneDrive.
               LiveUploadOperation uploadOperation = await connectClient.CreateBackgroundUploadAsync(folderId, "file.db", defaultDb, OverwriteOption.Rename);
               LiveOperationResult uploadResult = await uploadOperation.StartAsync();

          }
          catch (LiveAuthException ex)
            {
             // Handle errors.
            }
          catch (LiveConnectException ex)
            {
            // Handle errors.
            }
        }
    }
```

defaultDb is a StorageFile of the files I want to load.
folderId is the ID of the folder in OneDrive.

this is the exception:

```
 Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

thank you.

EDIT:

the problem is in the file to be uploaded, because if I select another file with the filepicker this is successful, instead, selecting my file that is in the folder localstate of application, is not working. it is possible that the reason why I can not upload it just because it is in the folder Localstate?

Comment: What's the unhandled exception you're getting??

Comment: None in particular, only crash.

Comment: Well, that exception being unhandled is the cause of the crash, and without knowing what it is, we cannot suggest possible causes, or methods to handle it safely.

Comment: I'm sorry now I saw:
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.ni.dll